# My 8gb sandisk shows 64 mb after installing ubuntu from it

Tags: installation, 13.10, live-usb

My 8gb sandisk shows only 64 mb now after installig ubuntu from it.I made start up disk of ubuntu and gave it to my friend.But when i got back my usb it shows 64mb and doesn't work on any operating sysytems[image]

Comment: format it once ..

Comment: Try creating a new partition table under the Device menu.

Comment: @Novine Got the answer here. Please post it as one.

Comment: i tried to format but it did'nt work,creating partition was not possible

Answer (score 0):

Create a new partition table under the Device menu. Default settings should be fine.